# OAuth token types and refreshing

Tags: android, oauth, google-api

In the [Cross-client Identity](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth) article by Google it's recommended to store OAuth refresh tokens on the server side.  
In the end of the article there is a sentence:

> Also, if the app always requested a refresh token without checking whether
>   the server already had one, this would eventually exhaust the finite
>   number of refresh tokens that can be outstanding for a user/app
>   combination

So I've got 2 questions:
1) Does it apply to [Android ID tokens](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth#androidIdTokens) and so should I save them in Android rather than calling `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` for every sync-with-server session?

2) How many types of OAuth tokens exist? Only in the mentioned article there are `ID token`, `access token` and `refresh token`. Is there somewhat like a summary on token types?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Android ID tokens has relatively small life span (3900 seconds) and they are cached by Android itself.
 So you **definitely** have to call `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` every time you need token

**2)** Token types are not something set once and forever. They depend on implementation and so have to be considered according to current purposes.